# Sublime Text build system for php and built-in web server

Tags: php, command-line-interface, webserver, sublimetext

For php I use the php built-in web server and the following build system, which opens the server page in Chrome:

```
{
    "cmd": ["open" , "-a" , "Chrome" , "http://localhost:8000/index.php"]
}
```

I enable the server by `php -S localhost:8000 -t <folder_path>` in the command line. How can I write a build system that it both enables the server and opens the server page? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not on a Mac at the moment to check it, but

```json
{
    "cmd": ["php", "-S", "localhost:8000", "-t", $project_path, "&&", 
            "open" , "-a" , "Chrome" , "http://localhost:8000/index.php"]
}
```

should do the trick, assuming `index.php` is in the same folder as your `.sublime-project` file.

I don't know how `php -S localhost:8000` behaves when there's another instance of `php` already serving to that port, so you may need to [cancel the build](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/build_systems.html#cancelling-a-build) or run `killall php` before building again. The danger with running `killall php` is that it'll kill any instances of php that are running an LSP server or linter, for example.

Comment: It does not work for Mac. I found the solution : {
 "shell": false,
    "cmd": ["sh", "-c", "open -a Chrome http://localhost:8000/index.html && php -S localhost:8000"]
}  but you need to cancel the build as you said